# Application not raising Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged event

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, suspend, hibernation

I've written a simple class to create an abstraction of `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged` event, this is the relevant code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class PowerStateMonitor

Private ReadOnly events As EventHandlerList

Public Custom Event SuspendInitiated As EventHandler(Of EventArgs)

    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of EventArgs))
        Me.events.AddHandler("SuspendInitiatedEvent", value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of EventArgs))
        Me.events.RemoveHandler("SuspendInitiatedEvent", value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim handler As EventHandler(Of EventArgs) =
            DirectCast(Me.events("SuspendInitiatedEvent"), 
                       EventHandler(Of EventArgs))

        If (handler IsNot Nothing) Then
            handler.Invoke(sender, e)
        End If
    End RaiseEvent

End Event

Public Custom Event SuspendResumed As EventHandler(Of EventArgs)

    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of EventArgs))
        Me.events.AddHandler("SuspendResumedEvent", value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of EventArgs))
        Me.events.RemoveHandler("SuspendResumedEvent", value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim handler As EventHandler(Of EventArgs) =
            DirectCast(Me.events("SuspendResumedEvent"), 
                       EventHandler(Of EventArgs))

        If (handler IsNot Nothing) Then
            handler.Invoke(sender, e)
        End If
    End RaiseEvent

End Event

Public Sub New()
    Me.events = New EventHandlerList
End Sub

Public Overridable Sub Start()
    AddHandler SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, AddressOf Me.SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub OnSuspendInitiatedEvent(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent SuspendInitiated(Me, e)
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub OnSuspendResumedEvent(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent SuspendResumed(Me, e)
End Sub

Private Sub SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
                                          ByVal e As PowerModeChangedEventArgs)

    Select Case e.Mode

        Case PowerModes.Suspend
            Me.OnSuspendInitiatedEvent(Nothing)

        Case PowerModes.Resume
            Me.OnSuspendResumedEvent(Nothing)

    End Select

End Sub

End Class
```

The problem is that when I call the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetSuspendState` to suspend or hibernate the system, the `SuspendInitiated` event of my class is not raised. I try to be notified of the Suspend state with this code below, but nothing happens because the value of `PowerModeChangedEventArgs.PowerModes` property never is `PowerModes.Suspend` so my event never raises.

```
Friend WithEvents PowerStateMon As New PowerStateMonitor

Public Sub Suspend(Optional ByVal force As Boolean = False)

    Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, force:=force, disableWakeEvent:=True)

End Sub

Private Sub PowerStateMon_SuspendInitiated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles PowerStateMon.SuspendInitiated

    ' Application.Exit()
    Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K Echo %TIME% The system is entering in Suspend state.")

End Sub
```

However, the oher event of my class, `SuspendResumed`, properlly notifies me when I resume the Suspend state:

```
Private Sub PowerStateMon_SuspendResumed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles PowerStateMon.SuspendResumed

    Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K Echo %TIME% The system resumed from Suspend state.")

End Sub
```

Please note the MSDN docs says:

- ***[Application.SetSuspendState Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)***

> Once an application responds to a suspend request, however, it can
>   take whatever time it needs to clean up resources and shut down active
>   processes.

What I'm missing?.

### UPDATE

I noticed that if I suspend the system in a normal behavior, I mean from the Windows startmenu, I'm notified about the Suspend, but If I use the `System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetSuspendState` method I'm not notified, as I said the value of `PowerModeChangedEventArgs.PowerModes` property never is `PowerModes.Suspend` this way, why?.